# eslint mulitline-ternary rule not fixing errors

Tags: eslint

I am one of those who prefers to have ternary expressions span multiple lines for readability. However, my current set-up is not fixing it as expected.

`eslint v7.17.0`

Here is the relevant part of my `.eslintrc.js`:

```
 rules: {
    'multiline-ternary': 'error',
    'operator-linebreak': ['error', 'after', { overrides: { '?': 'before', ':': 'before' } }],
 },
 ...
```

Both rules are fixable according to the docs:

[image: operator-linebreak with wrench] [image: multiline-ternary with wrench]

My npm lint script is `eslint --fix --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .`

However, I'm getting this in my console:

[image: console errors]

Why is it telling me that it is potentially fixable without fixing it?

Comment: In the docs it's mentioned that `The --fix option on the command line can automatically fix SOME of the problems reported by this rule.`